# How to delete a row being referenced in another table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

The question title might seem a bit vague. I am going to explain it here.

So, I have two tables:
1) Event
2) Contact

Event table has a foreign key (ContactID) referenced from Contact Table.
So when I delete a contact I have to first delete the event row which is using the contactID being deleted, to avoid any conflicts.

But I dont want that. Actually I use ContactID to get ContactName and ContactNumber while displaying Event details in a gridview along with other columns from event table.

This is the reason I dont want the event to be deleted I just want Null values for ContactName and ContactNumber.

I have tried setting ContactID as NULL in Event Table. Code:

```
string query0 = "Update Event SET ContactID=@contact where ContactID='" + cntID + "'";
SqlCommand cmd0 = new SqlCommand(query0, conn);
cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("contact", DBNull.Value);
conn.Open();
cmd0.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

This sets ContactID in Event Table to NULL just fine. But when I try to get Event Information in a gridview and apply a join on both tables I dont get the Event record where I set ContactId to NULL. 
This is the query to get event Info:

```
SELECT Event.ID, Event.StartDate, Event.Title, Contact.Name, Contact.Cell, Event.EventType, Event.Confirmed, Event.Comments 
FROM Event 
INNER JOIN Contact ON Event.ContactID = Contact.ID
```

What is the workaround for this? kindly help me and guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue with the final query is that you're using `INNER JOIN` which will only return results that exist in both tables. If you have events without a relevant contact then change it to a `LEFT JOIN`;

```
SELECT e.ID, e.StartDate, e.Title, c.Name, c.Cell, e.EventType, e.Confirmed, e.Comments 
FROM Event e
LEFT JOIN Contact c ON e.ContactID = c.ID
```

I've also updated the query to use table aliases.

Comment: This query runs fine on SQL Server Management Studio but the result is not reflected in the web interface. It still doesn't show the row where ContactID is NULL. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure on that one I'm afraid. Might be worth posting as a separate question.